# alienvault installation fails with gvm setup errors in log

Tags: security, linux-distributions, debian-buster

I'm trying to install the latest alienvault distribution and I've attempted installation on VirtualBox and ESXI both fail to complete the openvas GVM installation.

```
The first erros appear to be:
May  5 23:19:42 in-target:   Test completeness and readiness of GVM-11^M
May  5 23:19:42 in-target: Step 1: Checking OpenVAS (Scanner)... ^M
May  5 23:19:42 in-target:         OK: OpenVAS Scanner is present in version 7.0.1.^M
May  5 23:19:42 in-target:         ERROR: No CA certificate file for Server found.^M
May  5 23:19:42 in-target:         FIX: Run 'sudo runuser -u _gvm -- gvm-manage-certs -a -f'.^M
.
.
.
May  5 23:21:45 in-target: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of alienvault-dummy-framework:^M
May  5 23:21:45 in-target:  alienvault-dummy-framework depends on alienvault-gvm11-feed; however:^M
May  5 23:21:45 in-target:   Package alienvault-gvm11-feed is not configured yet.^M
May  5 23:21:45 in-target: ^M
May  5 23:21:45 in-target: dpkg: error processing package alienvault-dummy-framework (--configure):^M
May  5 23:21:45 in-target:  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured^M
```

Comment: Please consider giving more context to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they have had an open and unacknowledged bug that has broken installation for over 9 months now. I also couldn’t find help on SuperUser or and ChatGPT tried but those remedies didn’t work either.
https://success.alienvault.com/s/question/0D53q0000AhXea5CQC/ossim-installation-stalls-on-configuring-alienvaultgvm11feed-amd64./
It is possible to drop the installation in to jailbreak mode and remove the offending alienvault-dummy-framework with the following:

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

Remove the problematic packages: Run the following command to remove both alienvault-dummy-framework and alienvault-gvm11-feed:

sudo dpkg --remove alienvault-dummy-framework alienvault-gvm11-feed
Fix any broken dependencies: Run the following command to fix any broken dependencies:

sudo apt-get install -f
This command will attempt to resolve any unmet dependencies and fix the package configuration issues.

And then you can run OSSIM without OpenVAS if you don't need a vulnerability manager.  If you need a vulnerability manager try Nexpose, Wazuh or Nessus.